# Length of character array - C

Tags: c, linux

I've a pointer character array of

```
void main(){
    char* array[] = 
            {
                    [0] = "foo",
                    [1] = "bar",
                    [2] = "baz"
            };
read(array);
}
```

and when trying to fetch the lenght using `strlen`

```
int read(const char* events[]){
int size_of_events;
        size_of_events = (strlen(events));
}
```

it throws the following warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from test.c:6:0:
/usr/include/string.h:395:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

I can't understand what the problem is..

Comment: C never tracks the length of arrays. strlen simply iterates through characters until it finds a null character('\0') which is does add to the end of each of your string literals. So if you pass strlen a char**, which in your case points to a group of 3 pointers if it did work it would return a gibberish value. This error is the compiler saving you from something you almost certainly did not want.

Comment: To prevent possible future problems you may want to define the `array` as pointing to non-modifiable strings (which literal constants are): `const char *array[]`

Comment: You have to understand that C doesn't really "support" arrays *or* strings, it just kinda props them up on a couple of corners.  You need to tread very carefully when dealing with either, until you get the "feel" for it all.  (And even then there are pitfalls that can trap experienced C programmers.)

Comment: @hotlicks: I am an enthusiastic python programmer. but now it feels great to work on C - old, archaic language ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a string function on a pointer array.

In `read` (by the way don't use libc function names) `events` is of type `const char **` a.k.a a pointer to an array or `char *` pointers to char.

Using `strlen` on that will yield you unpredictable results. If you are lucky it will crash your program with a segmentation violation.

In C arrays do not inertially have a size or length. You need to pass that as a separate argument to your function.

The reason why `strlen` works on `char *` (character arrays) is because by convention strings in C are terminated by a special null-terminator symbol `'\0'`. it counts the amount of characters until the first '\n'. This is not the case for regular arrays.

If you want the lengths of the associated strings then you can obtain them with `strlen(events[0]), strlen(events[1]), strlen(events[2])`

Comment: I want the length of the pointer array and not the associated string lenghts. I tried the following strlen(events). It gives the correct result, but , it throws an error. It still has the same problem.

Comment: @user2015933 It is not possible to retrieve an arbitrary array's length in C if it is unknown. You have to pass it as a separate argument. Sorry, but this is what makes C both complicated, but also powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Youre trying to calculate `strlen` on a non-string - an array of strings in fact. `strlen` takes a `char *` as its argument while youre passing a `char **` (a pointer to an array of array of characters). See what happens with `strlen(events[0])` - should return 3, the length of `"foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

strlen give the length of a `char*` but you are passing a `char**`

I think you want the length of you array but you can't have it since you don't have NULL at the end

if your array was like:

```
char* array[] = 
        {
                [0] = "foo",
                [1] = "bar",
                [2] = "baz",
                [3] = NULL,   /* in stdlib.h */
        };
```

then you could go for something like

```
int read(const char* events[]){
        int size_of_events = 0;
        while (events[size_of_events] != NULL)
            size_of_events++;
        return (size_of_events);
}
```

If the size of your events array is unknown and you want to count it, then just add `NULL` at the end and then count

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in one string, not a string of strings.  Pass in one string using an index of one string instead of the **.